# How To Group Azure DevOps Build Artifacts From Multiple Projects Into One Release Pipeline By Just Build Artifact Tag

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

All the project builds for release 3 have been tagged with relese3. Out of 100 projects I'm not sure which ones are release3.  I need to group all the build artifacts from each project tagged with release3 into one release pipeline.  Is there a way to add build artifacts to a release by just build artifact tag?

Don't know which projects are tagged release3:
[image]

Is there any way to group build artifacts from multiple projects into one release pipeline by just build artifact tag?

Or can one release pipeline just use the Azure Trigger Pipeline task to trigger all project release pipelines with a build tag of release3?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/release/artifacts?view=azure-devops

Comment: I need to add all build artifacts from multiple projects by tag release3.  I'm not sure which projects to select from.  I don't want to add 100 projects by tag to the release pipeline.  Is there a way to add build artifacts to a release by just tag?

Answer (score 0):

> How To Group Azure DevOps Build Artifacts From Multiple Projects Into One Release Pipeline By Just Build Artifact Tag

I am afraid there is no such way to do this at this moment.

As we know, in the release pipeline, we need to specify the pipeline which need to be deployed.

We cannot leave the option source(build definition) blank (it is required). in addition,

If this function is supported, there will be a certain risk, because the release pipeline is directly related to production, and tags are used to bind all related build pipelines, which makes if our development engineers accidentally use the wrong tag, or in the wrong If the tag is added to the pipeline, the wrong build artifact will be released to the actual production environment because the pipeline is not clearly specified in the release pipeline. will cause losses.

If you feel this feature is important to you, you could add your request for this feature on our UserVoice site (https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/report?space=21&entry=suggestion), which is our main forum for product suggestions. Thank you for helping us build a better Azure DevOps.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the feedback.

So if you have 650 customers and out of 100 build pipelines only 30 applications and web services need to be deployed for release 3, you need to go through 650 release pipelines and update the 30 build artifacts that need to be deployed?

I'll try going the YAML route and see where I end up.